# Composer не добавляет папки

Tags: yii2, composer, kartik

Выполняю команду

```
composer require kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput "*"
```

Устанавливается пакет, все без ошибок

```
Updating kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput (dev-master c549564 => v1.0.6):  Checking out d2c8dcde1a
```

Однако, папка yii2-widget-fileinput не создается

Вот [библиотека](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput)

Вот [папки](https://yadi.sk/i/swCIVJP73YCTPu)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Только что попробовал оба варианта установки, проблем не возникло, все папки создались: http://joxi.ru/D2PLvYgtpkw4l2 Проверьте, может у Вас стоят ограничения на права к папке? Плюс попробуйте обновить composer. Или напрямую в composer.json в корне yii добавить в `require` элемент `"kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "*"` а потом выполнить обновление

Comment: тоже вышло сообщение, что все 3 папки добавлены. А по факту нет

Comment: тьфу ты. Моя невнимательность. оказывается выполнял compser update в другом проекте